# What's the command to monitor live streaming youtube page from youtube-dl?

Tags: downloads, streaming, youtube-dl

Okay so there is this youtube channel that was about live stream a religious lecture that I wanted to watch but I couldn't because I was out.

I want to know if there is any youtube-dl command that can keep monitoring a youtube channel and automatically begin downloading when the channel goes live?